# Core i5 memory limitations

Tags: intel-core-i5, core

it's long time since I upgraded my PC last time, so I still have C2D CPU.

I searched for some upgrades and found a few interesting things about Ci5 CPUs. From news I read I knew thay have built in memory controller, but what I didn´t know is that there are some limitations to them.

Core i5 limits max ram speed to 1333MHz. What to do with all the 1600 or even 2000MHz modules?

There is even limit to the RAM voltage. I believed that power supply of the RAM and the logic level are different things, so why does Ci5 limit RAM supply voltage? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you get your news, but I couldn't find anything that supports your theory. In fact, I found [just the opposite](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/corsair-launches-812gb-high-speed-memory-kits-for-core-i5i7-cpus/5275). Corsair introduced a kit of RAM *designed* for the Core i5/i7 that runs at 1600Mhz.

In short, the RAM should be compatible. But if you want to stick on the safe side, a huge chunk of the RAM industry touts its i5/i7 compatibility.

Comment: simply wrong, i3,5,7 only supporting up to 1066MHz, the Xeon are capable of 1333MHz. But you can use bigger than the supporting speed, but they will only run at speed the CPU/Socket will support.

Comment: well, i3 and i5 both supporting 1333MHz.

Comment: A lot depends on what "support" means.  If you have faster RAM and use it with the i5, it will by default run it only at the slower (1333MHz) speed; on the other hand, lots of motherboards will let you set a faster memory speed; on a third hand, if your i5 doesn't work properly with the faster memory speed, you have no recourse from Intel; on a fourth hand, almost all i5 chips do seem to work, as far as anyone can tell, with faster memory.

Comment: The power supply of the RAM and the logic level are entirely different things, but the memory controller is on the CPU chip, so made in the same process as the CPU chip, and that process isn't able to survive the higher voltages that some kinds of fast RAM intended for C2D systems could require.  So the voltage limit is a serious one, because setting a higher RAM voltage might damage your CPU and, again, you'll have no recourse from Intel if you do.

Comment: Oh, so, I know its strange question, but is there any reason intel did not separate power supply from memory controller? I mean, i dont know wheather RAM module directly changes voltage from supply to logical 1, or if that is what memorry controller does.

Comment: @schöppi I would've expected a large outcry from the overclocker and gaming community by now.